# Verificar se existe parâmetro na URL pelo PHP

Tags: php

Galera, é o seguinte...
Preciso verificar se na url existe um parâmetro (source) e pegar o valor que está sendo passado por ele...

Eu testei assim `$param = $_GET["source"];` mas se não tiver parâmetro nenhum na url, da um erro `Notice: Undefined index: source`.

Como faço pra ele só pegar o parâmetro caso exista?

Comment: Caio, conseguiu entender com a minha resposta?

Comment: @LeonardoNegrão sim cara, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro verifique se ela existe, assim:

```
if(isset($_GET['source'])) { //existe source?

$param = $_GET['source'];

}
else { //se não existir source, $param terá outro valor

$param = "";

}
```